# Difference between cl::Program constructors

Tags: c++, opencl

I was looking through the C++ bindings (http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-cplusplus-1.2.pdf), and I am trying to figure out the difference between these two constructors:

```
cl::Program::Program(const STRING_CLASS& source,
                     bool build = false,
                     cl_int * err = NULL)

cl::Program::Program(const Context& context,
                     const STRING_CLASS& source,
                     bool build,
                     cl_int * err = NULL)
```

What's the effect of passing a context vs. not passing one? I don't see it in the documentation for the constructors, so any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't pass a context, the header will use the default context (creating one if necessary), which is automatically created to contain all devices of type `CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT`. If you are not using the default context, then you will need to use the second overload to pass your own context explicitly.